# Override named entity with RegexNER instead of CRF model

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to detect named entities using Stanford CoreNLP in a task.

I have already given a rule as follows in my RegexNER mapping file as follows:

```
Train   VEHICLE_TYPE    2.0
```

But its identifying `Train` as `CRIMINAL_CHARGE` type of entity.

I have added this option `ner.applyFineGrained` and set it to `true` maybe that's why its overriding with CoreNLP's CRF model.

My question is how to add exceptions like this in RegexNER mapping file or is there some better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You should use these settings:

```
# run fine-grained NER with a custom rules file
java -Xmx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -ner.fine.regexner.mapping custom.rules -file example.txt -outputFormat text
```

You need to make sure to set `ner.fine.regexner.mapping` to your custom rules file to use that instead of the default fine-grained rules which would label things such as `CRIMINAL_CHARGE`

Comment: What is this flag `-ner.fine.regexner.mapping custom.rules`

Comment: The standard ner pipeline runs a rules file if `ner.applyFineGrained` is true.  That flag sets what the rule file.  If you don't set it, it will use the default.

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp please Help [https://stackoverflow.com/q/62189911/11537839](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62189911/11537839)